# setting proportionality for layout-small, large, xtra large with reference to existing Layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

Can anyone please suggest me what should I keep the textSize in terms of dp(in Layout-small,large,Extra Large) that would make the screen look aesthetically pleasing or would make it proportionate ? Any tips related to making layouts proportionate would be welcomed. Thank You ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create different `dimen.xml` files in `values` folder according to what you want your application to look like in different screen densities.